# What is the best way of CMake in a Middle-sized Project?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

In my company, we're developing a middle sized project which we plan to use CMake as the build platform generator. In this scenario, me and my colleagues were discussing about which way the CMake should be used. Our discussions came to a turn which we must decide the methods to use. Our directory structure is similar to this:

```
<"our project"> \
   modules \
      module_1 \
         tests \
            test_example.cpp
         mock
            some_mock_class.hpp
         some_class.hpp
         some_class.cpp
         ...
      module_2 \
         ...
      module_3 \
         ...
   utility \
      ...
```

1- First thing is first, my colleague thinks that folders like "src" and "includes" are reminder of C programming and has no place in a modern C++ program, so we don't need them. So we removed them from the structure, but being a Linux guy; I'm not sure if this is a good idea. Should we set a "include" directory for headers, so CMake can install them appropriately to the include dirs of the install target; or can CMake handle them appropriately?

2- Should we make a CMakeLists.txt to the root of the project which includes and defines all the targets, or should we make a CMakeLists.txt per module, and then use "add_subdirectory" directives to include them? My colleague thinks on CMakeLists.txt is the best, because this way the module implementors don't need to think about CMake at all, and one or two admins of deployment can maintain the file; but I think every module implementor is more aware of which libraries they use, and how to compile their modules - which he disagrees. What do you suggest in this case?

If you did use CMake for such a middle-sized project before (or know of a case) can you please recommend us what they did and, if possible, why?

Sincerely

Comment: Just one comment about your 2. point: one `CMakeLists.txt` per module/target is the right decision. From my experience the implementers of a module don't need to know CMake in depth. CMake is very straightforward and a implementer normally would just copy a `CMakeLists.txt` "template" from one of the other modules and change some of the properties. The admins can offer guidance with the more advance stuff e.g. if one of the modules need special handling. When the project grows larger, you may think about putting often used functionality into CMake macro/function wrappers.

Comment: And you could politely ask your colleague to see CMake as another kind of programming language where e.g. [modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) is a good idea (as you are doing it with your C++ code) and putting everything into one source file could be a bad thing.

Comment: He refers to those CMakeLists.txt files as "garbage" and says "he doesn't want to see those garbage in our source code"... So, I don't know if he can accept your argument objectively :) TBH; I'm pro of the "one per module" approach; it seems infinitely more easy to maintain, but I wanted to learn about good examples for convincing others ;)

Comment: And about your "template" approach: I actually did provide one to the other members; and they found it quite simple to use and even liked it (more than AutoTools); so this discussion was more for "future use decisions"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is huge, but in short my personal recommendation. For a middle project I assime a component model should be already applied. Then reasonable then is, to have component directories with their onwn CMakeLists.txt which are referenced by the top-level CMakeLists.txt via add_subdirectory(). Each component - a separate library (I like static ones).

For the component folders I find reasonable to hide all internal stuff (aka implementation and private headers, ...) under a `private` sub-directory to do not be exposed to the outside. Then, in the top component directory you have only headers which are to be used by the others. In the private directory you can mix sources and headers - this is only a matter of the taste for mid projects. And the private directory can also be decomposed if the component is large. But then you need to decide either to add all artifacts to the single CMakeLists.txt of the component, or to have sub-libraries. But in that case the users should link to them individually instead to link to the component's library only.

In the best case, the folder structure should follow the dependencies structure and form a tree-view build system, where the components have as less knowlege about internals of the other components as possible. In that case you will have a good configurability and flexibility in case of possible refactorings. In the other words, the design of the build system seems to me similar to the class design in C++ - same principles.

The real (target) build directory where you run cmake can be located anywhere, normally outside of the source directory. A good place for it could be a RAM disc if you enough memory. Then for the clean build you need just to remove it, that's it. But the source and the build itself have no dependency from its location.

Ah yes, one more hint. My recommendation would be to include headers by the path starting from the component directory like `#include "SomeHeader.hpp"` which is located as ComponentX/SomeHeader.hpp. Then the CMakelists.txt is used to do the `ComponentX` directory known to your component. This means, the paths to the headers are not hardcoded in the source files. This brings some limitation like unique file names, but makes changes to the components location much easier.

Hope this anyhow helps.

Comment: That last limitation was the drive when we were using "include/ComponentX/" folder to keep our headers and configure CMakeLists.txt accordingly; so that our libraries won't conflict with the system ones - in case of name clash. But now, I don't know what to do because of my colleagues motives confuse me. It's why I wanted to ask to the SO Community.

Comment: Yeah... with some time I got to a conclusion that in most cases it is very convenient to concentrate all dependencies (external paths resolution and linking) on cmake, but not on the code level. You may also hardcode the whole paths in the source code in includes. But in that case the dependencies are normally just multiplied because cmake in most cases already used for dependencies like to the system or third-party librarues located in non-standard paths. So, I though why the code should care about this.